# Windows Server loses path configuration on desktop shortcut

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

My remote desktop server users are having a lot of problems because, from time to time, one shortcut on their desktop loses its path.

The program is installed in C:\MyApp\app.exe but due to app design, it must be mounted through network share. Thus, the shared is created as:

T: -> \SERVER\Myapp

And from there I create the shortcut which has on its path: T:\app.exe

Everything goes well but, randomly in time, the path goes back from T:\app.exe to C:\MyApp\app.exe and stops working.

This is a 2012R2 box but I cannot find any clue as to what this is happening.

Any hints?

Comment: Does the user mapping drive always work as expected ? as I wonder if a path not found error happen to the user, and they click to search the .exe from that windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a default feature of Windows.  To disable in group policy, enable this setting:

User > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > File Explorer:

*Do not track Shell shortcuts during roaming*

You should also enable these settings:

User > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar:

*Do not use the search-based method when resolving shell shortcuts

Do not use the tracking-based method when resolving shell shortcuts*